# ionic framework / cordova IOS : open local file - local file path

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I'm trying without success to open some local files with the CordovaFileopener2
Can somebody post a sample of code on how generate a local file path?

I need for example to point www/pdf/document1.pdf

Thanks a lot for your help

Alfonso

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have uploaded a sample project for file Transfer in [git hub](https://github.com/anilkumar007/File_Transfer)
Please have a look and reply, if you have any queries