# How can I access a downloaded file in the local filesystem of iOS using Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the [cordova-file-transfer-plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) and I am able to download and play an MP3 file perfectly on Android but on iOS the file does not exist.

I changed the directory to `documentsDirectory` but when I call it in my browser it doesn't work. I am using the code example shown on the link.

I have also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072337/ionic-framework-cordova-ios-open-local-file-local-file-path) but no luck.

```
 var targetPath;
                    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS())
                    {
                        targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + data.value.split('/').pop();
                    } else
                    {
                        targetPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + data.value.split('/').pop();
                    }
                    $cordovaFileTransfer.download('http://admin.lalelaknowledge.com/FileUpload/Upload/0a5eabcc-231e-4831-b72f-c8980b78615c.mp3', targetPath, {}, true)
                            .then(function (result)
                            {
                                console.log(result);

                            }, function (err) {

                                console.log(err);
                            }, function (progress) {
                                $timeout(function () {
                                    console.log((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100);
                                });
                            });
```

Comment: Could you share some of your code?

Comment: just added it. FYi it works fine in a IOS simulator but not on device.

Comment: Hi @duovili.. may i ask if your download function didn't have issues? Mine works if i restart the app only..

Comment: It was because I was using a new webview that used different paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution. You need cordova cordovaFileOpener2 plugin to open this file. Hope you already installed it. Let me know it worked ornot.

```js
$scope.initializeDownload = function() {
  var fileName = '0a5eabcc-231e-4831-b72f-c8980b78615c.mp3'
  var storagePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileName
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(storagePath, function success(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
      $scope.downloadAttachment(file.localURL, options, trustHosts)
    })
  }, function(err) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.documentsDirectory,
      function success(dirEntry) {
        dirEntry.getFile(fileName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''), {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
          },
          function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
              $scope.downloadAttachment(file.localURL, options, trustHosts)
            });
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error)
          });
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      });
  });
}


$scope.downloadAttachment = function(fileURL, trustHosts, options) {
  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  ft.onprogress = function(progress) {
    // Here you can get your download status
    //var downloadStatus = (progress.loaded / parseInt(fileSize)) * 100;
    //console.log(downloadStatus)
  };
  ft.download('http://admin.lalelaknowledge.com/FileUpload/Upload/0a5eabcc-231e-4831-b72f-c8980b78615c.mp3',
    fileURL,
    function(result) {
//Second argument is the file Mime type
      $cordovaFileOpener2.open(result.nativeURL, 'audio/mpeg').then(function(result) {
        console.log("Open success")
      }, function(err) {
        console.log("Open Error")
      });
    },
    function(error) {
      ft.abort();
      console.log(error.exception || error.body)
    },
    trustHosts,
    options
  );
}
```

Comment: but doesnt this plugin open it in the native mp3 player? I want to  open it in the app using the HTML player in the app.

Comment: What experience you are getting right now? Whatever i learned from cordova it will give option user to choose app to open any file.

Comment: On android device and IOS simulator it calls the file no problem (with absolute file URL) and plays it but on an IOS device in the console it just says 'an error occurred while getting the resource', and I know for a fact that the resource is there.